# Most time/space efficient data structure for filtering and aggregating relational data

Tags: data-structures, reporting, aggregate-functions

Imaging a test-taking application which has the following models and relationships:

```
Test -< Categories -< Questions -< Answers
Question >-< Domain
```

So a test has many category, and each category are several questions.  A question can also have several domains and a domain can have many questions (similar to "tags").
Using the application, a user takes a test, creating answers to specific categories.

If we wanted to ask:

- what is the test mean for test X (mean of category means)
- what is the category mean (mean of questions in the category)
- what is the question mean (mean of answer values for question)
- what is the domain mean (mean of question means for domain)

...what is the most space/time efficient data structure, or database layout to ask these kinds of questions?

A matrix based solution or other in-memory data-structure, or normalized NoSQL solution, is preferable to one that involves persisting the data and then pulling it out with joins.